# Rails generator error rspec [not found]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, generator, rspec-rails

I am using rails 4.1.1

When I execute the command `rails g generator my_generator`

The generator runs but always ends with `error rspec [not found]`

I have added the `rspec` and `rspec-rails` gems to my Gemfile.

What step am I missing to get this working?

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to add `rspec` to your gem files, just `rspec-rails`.

After you `bundle install` run `rails generate rspec:install` and everything should work fine.

Comment: I removed rspec from the Gemfile. I run bundle install again I ran the rails generate rspec:install command again and the output showed identical files to what had already been generated and still gave the rspec [not found] error.

Comment: You will need to create them manually then, apparently rspec will not create spec files when you use the `rails g generator`. Is not only you who has this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to install RSpec by the the `rspec-rails` [repository](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) is:

Add `rspec-rails` to both the `:development` and `:test` groups in the Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
end
```

After that run `bundle install` and your RSpec should run fine.